# Writing files to Android device on Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: android, firebase, junit4

I am writing JUnit4 tests that run on Android Pixel API28 using Flank/Firebase Test Lab, and trying to write some metadata to the test device to any public `/sdcard/*` folder and download the metadata for further processing.

I have tried so many variations of the code below at this point, but none seem to have worked:

```
        // val folder = "/storage/emulated/0/Download"
        // val folder = "/sdcard/Android/Download"
        val folder = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath
        val fileName = "$folder/Result-$testCaseId.json"

        try {
            val myObj = File(fileName)
            if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
                Log.i("MetadataListener", "File created: " + myObj.getName())
            } else {
                Log.i("MetadataListener", "File already exists.")
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // println("An error occurred.")
            Log.e("MetadataListener", "Error message" + e.message)
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

I have also tried to enable write permissions in my `AndroidManifest.xml` but this didn't do anything. I don't think I should need these permissions either, because I'm trying to write to the public Downloads folder:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Anyone have any idea what's wrong here?
When I debug against my local device and step through the code, this code does run without errors. :(

Any advice would be really appreciated here, and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I have learned in solving this issue:

1. By default Flank provides all permissions, so explicitly enabling write permissions is unnecessary for a Flank/Firebase Test Lab configuration. This was not my issue.
2. The root cause was that this code actually was not running. It turns out that Firebase Test Lab was not accepting my configuration parameters when registering a listener with the test runner in my Gradle plugin code:

```
project.configure<LibraryExtension> {
  defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner = "com.mypackage.TestRunner"
  defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunnerArgument("listener", "com.mypackage.MetadataListener)
}
```

The workaround and accepted answer that resolves my issue was explicitly adding a listener to my test runner at runtime, rather than at build time:

```
class TestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun onCreate(arguments: Bundle) {
        arguments.putString("listener", MetadataListener::class.java.name)
        super.onCreate(arguments)
    }
}
```